# Python Selenium Use Cookies for Security Code Bypass

Tags: python, selenium

All I am trying to do is to start a fresh selenium browser and to be already logged in on this specific website. I know that I have to use pickle and cookies (save_cookies and the load_cookies), because I tried this on https://www.facebook.com/ and it worked (I was already logged in). My guess is that, because the site, that I want to work with has a Security Code Check (meaning I enter the email and password for the account, but they send me a verification code via email, that needs to be inserted), it can't work with cookies like facebook worked. So, can I achieve this via cookies, is there another way or is it possible at all?

Comment: Just a suggestion but could you not use the mail services POP/IMAP server and get the verification code?

Comment: I've already been using a method to overcome my issue and that is I opened a different browser window that contains my email account logged in page, that refreshes until it gets the expected code (but it's very slow and annoying). I am not very familiar with POP/IMAP and I would like to know if there are any benefits regarding my workaround.

Comment: Well, as you said, your workaround is slow and performance intensive (a whole new browser window) as opposed to repetitive calls to your IMAP/POP server. I am not familiar with the cookie method which is why I am offering this suggestion. Perhaps another user can help better

Comment: Ok. Thank you anyway !